# In firebase, how to add custom claims to root node, instead of "claims"?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

In my cloud function, I need to create a customtoken and insert some custom claims. I do so like this:

```
     let additionalClaims = {
     'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims': {
       'x-hasura-default-role': 'admin',
       'x-hasura-allowed-roles': ['user', 'admin'],
       }
     }

      admin.auth().createCustomToken(userId,additionalClaims).then(function (customToken) {
       console.log(customToken);
        response.end(JSON.stringify({
          token: customToken
        }))
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
      });
```

The Claims get added, but they are put in a "claims" node, that looks like this:

```
     {
      "aud": 
      "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      "iat": 1573160781,
      "exp": 1573164381,
      "iss": "postgrest-b4c8c@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "sub": "postgrest-b4c8c@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "uid": "mikeuserid",
      "claims": {
           'https://hasura.io/jwt/claims': {
           'x-hasura-default-role': 'admin',
           'x-hasura-allowed-roles': ['user', 'admin'],
          }
         }
       }
      }
```

However, the API I am calling is expecting them in the root, like this:

```
                {
      "aud": 
      "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
      "iat": 1573160781,
      "exp": 1573164381,
      "iss": "postgrest-b4c8c@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "sub": "postgrest-b4c8c@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
      "uid": "mikeuserid",
      "https://hasura.io/jwt/claims": {
      "x-hasura-default-role": "admin",
      "x-hasura-allowed-roles": ["user", "admin"],
          }
       }
      }
```

How can I add the claims so they are added to root, and not under "claims" ??

FYI, if I have an existing user, and use this syntax
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(customToken, additionalClaims),

It correctly adds them root.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add claims to the top-level (root) of a Firebase custom token. You should also not pass custom tokens to other APIs. They should only be used to initiate a sign-in from a client device. The sign-in operation will exchange the custom token for an ID token with the custom claims at the root of the JWT.

When you add claims using `setCustomUserClaims()`, there are no custom tokens involved (usually). The user receives an ID token from Firebase Auth, with custom claims already set at the root.

Comment: Thx, I realized that today, two different tokens altogether. If you have a cloud function that, let's say needs to call a 3rd party API and pass a JWT token(with a specific claim) in the Authorization header, how would you do that? Or is it not possible?